# How to simplify topological surface in blender 2.83.3?

Tags: sculpting, topology

I've been playing with Blender for the past month now, and I'm in the situation where I need to finalize a model that I sculpted from a tutorial. I'm trying to follow the tutorial, but I got lost on a part where the tutorial simplifies the topological surface. He creates vertices on the surface and its blowing my mind (check out the screenshot if needed). Any ideas would be much appreciated. :)

[image]

Comment: it's called retopology, you'll find a lot of tutorials about it, you need to create a second mesh and activate the Snapping option (Face mode) so that your second mesh stick to the surface of the high-poly

Comment: Holy moly, moon you're a god. Thank you for telling me that term, I would've never gotten it. Thanks!

Comment: watch https://www.blendernation.com/2020/08/09/introduction-to-retopology-with-blender-2-8/ the video is way too long, but the first few minutes of it will show you how some strategies for retopo and how to get started.